# Filter data where the value in three columns is the same

Tags: python, pandas

I am importing a CSV into Python and I want to filter the column to show only rows that have 4 values that are consistent EG

```
ID,  Name,  Performance test 1 , Performance test 2 , Performance test 3, Performance test 4, Consistent?
1    Bob    Pass                 Pass                 Pass                 Pass               TRUE 
2    Dave   Pass                 Fail                 Pass                 Pass               FALSE
3    Roger  Fail                 Fail                 Fail                 Fail               TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with test if all values per rows are unique by [`DataFrame.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) compared by `1`:

```
df['Consistent?'] = df.filter(like='Performance test').nunique(axis=1).eq(1)
print (df)

   ID   Name Performance test 1 Performance test 2 Performance test 3  \
0   1    Bob               Pass               Pass               Pass   
1   2   Dave               Pass               Fail               Pass   
2   3  Roger               Fail               Fail               Fail   

  Performance test 4  Consistent?  
0               Pass         True  
1               Pass        False  
2               Fail         True
```

For improve performance compare all values by first filtered column with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for test if all `True`s per rows:

```
df1 = df.filter(like='Performance test')
df['Consistent?'] = df1.eq(df1.iloc[:, 0], axis=0).all(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks , On my spreadsheet they have different names though not just performance test  EG , GCSE, A Level, University , Post grad

Comment: There is also multiple other columns that aren't relevant to this

Comment: @NicolaHodge - then change `df.filter(like='Performance test')` to `df[['GCSE','A Level','University','Post grad']]` all columns for test in list

Comment: Thankyou, I think I'm doing something wrong I am getting NameError: name 'df' is not defined

Comment: @NicolaHodge - what is name of your dataframe? if use  `df = pd.read_csv(file)` then `df` is DataFrame used in my solution.

Comment: Sorry , Yes its running now but it is displaying only the filtered columns with all results, not just where the results are consistent

Comment: @NicolaHodge - What is your code?

Comment: df1 = df[['GCSE','Alevel','Assesment','FinalExam']]
df['Consistent?'] = df1.eq(df1.iloc[:, 0], axis=0).all(axis=1)

Comment: @NicolaHodge - Do you need remove columns after test like `df = df.drop(['GCSE','Alevel','Assesment','FinalExam'], axis=1)` after my solution?

Comment: It isn't displaying the column Consistent

Comment: I got it! Thanks for your help!

Comment: If I wanted to filter the result further to just show performers with only passes, how could I do that please? Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

This way is a bit longer, but it's explicit, which may help you modify it according to what you want. The values in the columns "Performance Test 2", "Performance Test 3" & "Performance Test 4" are compared to those in "Performance Test 1" to see if they are all equal.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    data = {'ID':[1,2,3], 'Name':['Bob', 'Dave', 'Roger'], 'Performance Test 1':["Pass", "Pass", "Fail"], 'Performance Test 2':["Pass", "Fail", "Fail"], 'Performance Test 3':["Pass", "Pass", "Fail"], 'Performance Test 4':["Pass", "Pass", "Fail"]} 

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    df['Consistent?'] = np.where((df['Performance Test 1'] == df['Performance Test 2']) & (df['Performance Test 1'] == df['Performance Test 3']) & (df['Performance Test 1'] == df['Performance Test 4']), 1, 0)
    df.head()
```

```
        Out[9]: 
   ID   Name Performance Test 1 Performance Test 2 Performance Test 3  \
0   1    Bob               Pass               Pass               Pass   
1   2   Dave               Pass               Fail               Pass   
2   3  Roger               Fail               Fail               Fail   

  Performance Test 4  Consistent?  
0               Pass            1  
1               Pass            0  
2               Fail            1
```